# What audio and video formats should I accept in HTML?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have an `input` and a `video`:

```
<input type="file">
<video></video>
```

When I upload something to the `input`, it gets played on the `video` element.

What file formats for audio and video are safe to accept?

I have found that `mp4`, `webm`, `ogg`, and a few others are the main ones to use, but I'm wondering if any others are fine to accept, or if I can just use `video/*, audio/*`, as well as the browser compatibility for these others.

Comment: I found `video/mp4, audio/mp4, audio/mp3, audio/ogg, video/ogg, audio/wav, video/webm, .mp4, .mp3, .ogg, .ogv, .oga, .wav, .webm, .m4a` to work the best...

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*">
```

I think you can use all of them as video extensions.